# Regex replacement of number

Tags: regex

I have a simple regex question. 
In a set of URLs, I need to replace the occurrence of `?page=X` with `?page=Y`. 
Now `X` could be either single digit or 2 digits.

Hence,

`?page=1` will need to be replaced to say `?page=20`

or

`?page=20` could need to be replaced with say, `?page=1`

I think this might be quite trivial, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `\?page=\d\d?` or `\?page=\d{1,2}`

Comment: I really hope there is some requirement on this forum to comment on why a negative is being given on a question - If it is not clear, please say so. Being new to the forum doesn't mean we are totally dumb. Just that we got here later and are new to this particular programming language.

Comment: It's expected to show some effort toward solution prior to asking question. When you stumble at something then ask question. PS: I didn't down voted.

Comment: Most likely because you did not provide any code that shows that you have tried to solve this yourself.

Comment: What do you define as effort ? Is it the effort of noob or an expert ?

Comment: @tomtomossi Fair point. I didn't know that. Will do so in future.

Comment: Did you Google "replace text" yet? I would guess not. Also, were you going to use a Mac to do this? Sticks? Imagination? You've listed an impossibly vague question here.

Comment: @rock Works. Thanks. Would have accepted if posted an answer.

Comment: @LinxuDisciple What was seeming impossible and vague for you does seem to have an accurate answer in minutes. Yes I am a noob, but I don't think the question was that vague. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @PVR I already posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search with regex like this `\?page=\d{1,2}` and replacement with `?page=20` or whatever you number is will do.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI7uA1/1)**

Answer (score 0):

These are the following ways that I can think of

**Sol 1**

```
\?page=\d\d?
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\? #Match question mark
page= #Match the string page=
\d #Match a single digit from [0-9]
\d? #Match a single digit from [0-9] (? indicates that previous part is OPTIONAL)
```

**Sol 2**

```
\?page=\d{1,2}
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\? #Match question mark
page= #Match the string page=
\d{1,2} #Match a single digit from [0-9] once or twice as indicated by the range {1-2}
```

This will only detect the text. You have to use `replace` as per your language for replacement

Comment: Wow ! thanks for such a detailed answer and effort. I am not such a big noob though :) Would have accepted, if i didnt already accept the previous answer. My teeny reputation doesnt allow me to upvote either !

Comment: @PVR Its allright. It took some time to write the answer. I thought to include an explanation in case you are completely new to `regex`